# continuous deployment with github pages and GAE python

Tags: google-app-engine, github

I have a site hosted by google app engine. I've pushed all the html files to a github pages repo and what I want to do next is somehow make GAE listen to my github's changes. Like everytime i commit something new, GAE will deploy itself based on the changes.
I've heared of drydrop but that was when github pages didn't exist yet.

So what should i do next? I've set up a post-receive url , which is my appspot website, through the github's service hooks, added the CNAME file to my repo which contains my appspot url. Not sure if that's necessary.

I've googled a lot on this but none really answers my question. or I just don't know the right search term for it.

Comment: In summary, you only want to publish the code ONCE and it will magically appear in both places? Suggestion: Update appcfg.py to include a push to github (anyone have a better idea instead of my  band-aid-answer)

Comment: yea I mean, when i commit something to github, it will somehow deploy to GAE too...maybe it's a bit too much to ask for

Comment: The drydrop FAQ says "GitHub Pages solves the same need of "live-hosting of GitHub repository as a static site on custom domain". I started this project before GitHub Pages was announced and GitHub pages made it somewhat obsolete, especially because they support jekyll, which is cool.". Given that, what feature does App Engine / DryDrop have that you want to use, that Github pages doesn't?

Comment: @NickJohnson Please correct me if i'm wrong. The feature I want that Github pages doesn't have but DryDrop does is that DryDrop allows me to be able to deploy my appspot site based on the commits I make through Github. I read the FAQ, that's why I thought Github pages must be able to do it without DryDrop but right now I can't do it. At least i don't know how to direct the github pages to my appspot domain, even though i already included the CNAME file.

Comment: @BPm But why do you want to deploy to App Engine at all, if everything you need is already provided by Github pages?

Comment: @NickJohnson because i originally wrote my site for app engine and most of the features are written for app engine. i just dont want to rewrite it. I want to use Git and GAE at the same time, first for practice and second keeps the record of all changes... it's fine i guess. I'll just stick to GAE.

Comment: @BPm It sounds like you would be best just checking your app's source into Git, and managing it like that, then deploying manually.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to go through this extra effort to achieve the function you want?
If I understand correctly, it's like you want a button on github or googlecode with "deploy to appspot" and technically I think it is doable if you really want but I suggested this as a feature to googlecode several years ago: Editable repository, which google started with recently so that you can edit your files directly in the repository, and I also suggest deployment directly from googlecode like a button saying "deploy my project to appspot" and then we don't need local development anymore.

However the story is that they dropped that feature request and I can understand why since a lot of things can go wrong and your repository might not be a standard place to deploy from since it is not uncommon to include files to the project that are not in the repository and that seems impossible if you have some part of the code that you must change a little right before deployment without versioning that code ie a password or a secret key that you need to deploy without putting it in source control.

I called this idea "3in1": The repository can 3 things in one: 1) versioning 2) edit files and 3) deploy the files where only the first is a core function of the repository.

You could setup a schedular deployment machine that runs a cron job or so that takes the latest code from your repository and deploys it if it changed if you really want to enable this feature.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I just wanted to be able to do the same thing like drydrop http://drydrop.binaryage.com/  ...it just sounds so cool